# Find the complex number $z$ for which the following is true: $|z-1|=|z|$ and $\arg(z^3)=\frac{\pi}{3}+ \arg(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the complex number $z$ for which the following is true: $|z-1|=|z|$ and $\arg(z^3)=\frac{\pi}{3}+ \arg(z).$ The answer is given in, but in the very beginning, I am having trouble seeing how this deduction is made:

Let's write $z=r\cos\varphi+ir\sin\varphi$.

The first condition gives:
$$(r\cos\varphi-1)^2+(r\sin\varphi)^2=r^2$$ How does the first condition equivalent to this, is my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:
$$\text{z}=\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i=\left|\text{z}\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi k\right)i}$$
Where $\left|\text{z}\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$,$\arg\left(\text{z}\right)$ is the complex argument of $\text{z}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

So, we get:

1. $$\left|\text{z}-1\right|=\left|\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i-1\right|=\sqrt{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]-1\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$$
2. $$\left|\text{z}\right|=\left|\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$$
3. $$\arg\left(\text{z}^3\right)=\arg\left(\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right)^3\right)=3\arg\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right)$$

Now:

- $$\left|\text{z}-1\right|=\left|\text{z}\right|\Longleftrightarrow\sqrt{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]-1\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}=\sqrt{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$$
- $$\arg\left(\text{z}^3\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}+\arg\left(\text{z}\right)\Longleftrightarrow3\arg\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}+\arg\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

Writing $z = r e^{i \theta}$ we have from the second condition that $3 \theta = \frac{\pi}{3} + \theta$ so $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Then use your condition to deduce $r$.

Comment: In fact one can easily deduce that the real part of your solution must be $1/2$ so you dont even need to compute sin or cos of the angle.

Comment: My question is just: Why is the first condition equivalent to $(r\cosφ−1)^2+(r\sinφ)^2=r^2$

Answer (score -1):

As you pointed out, the first condition is equivalent to $(r\cosφ−1)^2+(r\sinφ)^2=r^2$. Substituting into the LHS second condition and using [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), we get:

$$\arg z^3=\arg((r\cosφ+ir\sinφ)^3)=3φ$$

Equating this to the RHS of condition $2$ gives us:

$$3φ=\frac{\pi}{3}+φ$$

And hence, $φ=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and we can solve condition $1$ for $r$.

Comment: My question is just: Why is the first condition equivalent to $(r\cosφ−1)^2+(r\sinφ)^2=r^2$

Comment: @BozoVulicevic You've set $z=r(\cos φ+i\sinφ)$ in mod-arg form. This means that $|z|=r$. Clearly $z-1$ is going to equal $(r-1)\cosφ+ri\sinφ$ because it's just $z$ with its real part reduced by $1$. Square the real and imaginary parts (as per the definition of a modulus) and you get $|z-1|^2=(r\cosφ-1)^2+(r\sinφ)^2$. Equate the two moduli and you get it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Upvoted.

Comment: @BozoVulicevic No probs dude.